# react upload multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I am trying to get my form to upload several files, but once I upload the first one, I have no chance to load a second one. Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my upload component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as RB from 'react-bootstrap'

import Button from 'components/Button/Button'

class uploadMob extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            files: [],
        }
    }

    onFilesAdded = (e) => {
        const filesArray = this.state.files
        filesArray.push(e.target.files[0])
        this.setState({ files: filesArray })

        this.uploadFiles()
    }

    async uploadFiles() {
        this.state.files.forEach((file) => {
            this.sendRequest(file)
        })
    }

    sendRequest(file) {
        const { pdfUploadToState } = this.props
        pdfUploadToState(file)
    }

    render() {
        const files = this.state.files
        return (
            <RB.Form.Group>
                <div className="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <div className="Files">
                        {files.map((file, key) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={key} className="Row">
                                    <span className="Filename">
                                        {file.name}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <Button size="sm" variant="light">
                        Dateien hochladen
                    </Button>

                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="files"
                        id="files"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.onFilesAdded(e)
                        }}
                        multiple
                    />
                </div>
            </RB.Form.Group>
        )
    }
}

export default uploadMob
```

The first file is uploaded perfectly, but as mentioned, the button does not respond when trying to upload a second one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will have to upload multiple files using multiple select using control key on keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply niks. The problem is that also when selecting multiple files, it loads only the first. Anyway, whithout the "multiple" atribute on input, the button does not work  when hitting for the second time..

Comment: It might be happening because of  this : filesArray.push(e.target.files[0]). you are pushing only 0th element in array.

Comment: I thought that too, but because this is my version for mobile, I want actually to load files one by one. I tried anyway all variations to get the e.target.files and none of them worked. I am quite lost on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct but when you use input type file with multiple attribute you need to select multiple files and then hit upload button insted of selecting files one by one.

also replace

```
    filesArray.push(e.target.files[0])
```

with

```
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        filesArray.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
```

to upload file one by one 
 replace

```
     onFilesAdded = (e) => 
    {
      this.state.files.push(e.target.files[0])
      this.uploadFiles()
    }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arunkumar. The problem is that also when selecting multiple files, it loads only the first. Anyway, whithout the "multiple" atribute on input, the button does not work when hitting for the second time..  I do want actually to load files one by one, because this is my mobile-version, but I dont know what is wrong in the code.